# Spring Security entity field level security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC application which presents a view which shows all of the fields from a `Customer` entity such as name, address, phone number etc. The application has various roles such as `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`. Users with `ROLE_USER` are only able to see the customer name where as users with `ROLE_ADMIN` can see all of the customer fields.

At the moment the way I have implemented this is with a [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org) view which makes use of the [SpringSecurityDialect](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity) to restrict access to certain fields based on the user's role:

```
<th:block sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  <div th:text="${customer.phoneNumber}" />
</th:block>
```

Whilst this works absolutely fine it doesn't feel right and it's difficult to test. I would like to write tests against the controller which call the controller method with a principal that has different roles such as `testViewCustomerAsRoleAdmin` and `testViewCustomerAsRoleUser`. This isn't possible to verify as the controller returns a `Customer` to the view which is fully populated and has every field accessible via the getters.

What I'm after is some sort of field level security at the entity level where I can make use of the Spring Security annotations:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String getPhoneNumber()
{
  return phoneNumber;
}
```

It would be ideal if this could then raise an `AccessDeniedException` when trying to access the field if the principal is not authorized.

The Jersey project seems to have this sort of concept which is mentioned [here](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/04/filtering-jax-rs-entities-with-standard-security-annotations/), [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.security.annotations) and an example [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/entity-filtering-security/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/entityfiltering/security/domain/RestrictedSubEntity.java). It does however seem to be limited to role based security rather than the full SpEL support offered with `@PreAuthorize`

Is there any way or implementing this sort of thing with Spring Security, I know the security context or SpEL evaluation context is not available in entities as they are not Spring managed. If not, is there any other approach which might allow me to achieve the same thing?

**EDIT:**

I don't know the Spring Security framework inside out but it seems like something that might be able to be done using Spring AOP in ApectJ mode to instrument methods of domain (entity) classes. It would then be a case of getting hold of the `AccessDecisionManager` and passing along the authentication (presumably obtained from the `SecurityContextHolder`) along with the contents of the annotation on the domain class methods (if present). Does anyone have experience with doing this sort of thing?

Comment: How about database proxy authentication (impersonation) combined w column-level security?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I'm really looking for a application level solution for this problem, the things you've mentioned are database specific which doesn't work for a web application which maintains a connection pool to the database under a single user.

Comment: You can 100% make it work with pooling

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I'm not really looking for a database level solution as it's a portable Spring Boot application designed to work with the likes of MySQL and PostgreSQL and require no database administration. I've not really come across the concepts you've mentioned, could you explain how they work? I'm currently looking into AspectJ in more detail as I think it could provide the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem using Spring AOP in AspectJ mode. The various Spring annotations such as `@Transactional` and `@PreAuthorize` will work on any non-Spring managed classes if you enable AspectJ mode and perform either compile time or load time weaving, there is a very good example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/aspectj-jc

You need to make sure you have the `spring-security-aspects` dependency in your project (or plugin if you're using compile-time weaving) to enable weaving of `@Secured` annotations. Despite the comment in `AnnotationSecurityAspect` which describes the class as:

> Concrete AspectJ aspect using Spring Security @Secured annotation for
>   JDK 1.5+.

The class does actually weave the other Spring annotations including `@PreAuthorize`, `@PreFilter`, `@PostAuthorize` and `@PostFilter`.